How to get HRESULT from method invoked by CComDispatchDriver InvokeN?
I am trying to invoke methods from differnt com servers using late binding:
HRESULT hr = drv.InvokeN(dispid, params.data(), static_cast<int>(params.size()), &retVal);
if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) {...}

If the method I am invoking returns a custom HRESULT, InvokeN just returns 0x80020009 (exception occured).
How can I retrieve the "original" HRESULT?
Some of the servers have IErrorInfo implemented.
In this case I can retrieve an error description:
    IErrorInfo* pErrorInfo = nullptr;
    GetErrorInfo(0, &pErrorInfo);
    if (pErrorInfo != nullptr) {
        BSTR description;
        if (SUCCEEDED(pErrorInfo->GetDescription(&description))) {
            // Do something with the error description
            SysFreeString(description);

        }
        // Release the error info object
        pErrorInfo->Release();
    }

But not the HRESULT.
I also tried GetLastError, but this returns always 0.
So how can I retrieve the HRESULT returned by the invoked method?

That's what the pExcepInfo parameter for IDispatch::Invoke() is meant to relay back.  InvokeN() does very little, just call Invoke() yourself.

Thank you for pointing me in this direction.
